# sailsjs v0.11 and express-validator

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I have had some issues setting up SailsJS to use the express-validator middleware.

I ended up using the a custom middleware to get it to work :

```
  customMiddleware: function(app){
    var v= require('express-validator');
    app.use(v());
  }
```

Any advise on getting this to work with the accepted method of using 3rd party middleware would be appreciated. I have gone trough a couple of questions , forum posts plus the documentation but the above method was the only way I could get this to work so I can continue the development.

1. http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Middleware
2. https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator

Comment: If you describe what your "some issues" are, we can help. Otherwise, we have no idea what problems you ran into, and thus cannot fix them.

Comment: @TravisWebb hi , basically I couldn't get express-validator to work without using the customMiddleware opt. There were many other recommended ways :(

Answer (score 1):

I had no problems getting the following to work without needing to use the "customMiddleware" function. I believe this is the recommended approach.

In `config/http.js`, note the added `expressValidator` property and the `'expressValidator'` entry in the `order[]` stack JUST BEFORE the `'bodyParser'`.

```
order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'expressValidator',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      //'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
],

expressValidator: require('express-validator')()
```